# Access Vue Props with Unconventional Characters

Tags: vue.js, auth0, nuxt.js

Using Auth0, I have a the following in the jwt token:

```
{
...
"email": "email@me.com",
"https://portal.monogram.io/timezone": "America/New_York"
...
}
```

I get that email will be something like `loggedUser.email` but how would I get the `https://portal.monogram.io/timezone`?

Comment: `loggedUser['https://portal.monogram.io/timezone']` perhaps?

Comment: Uhm, yeaaaah... that was it. Would you care to add it as an answer?